# string(int), string(int32) and string([]int32) are all valid but string([]int) is invalid - what's the rationale here?

Tags: string, go, slice, rune

(I'm using Go 1.14.6.)

The following statements would all output the char `a`

```
Println(string(int(97) ) )
Println(string(int32(97) ) )
Println(string([]int32{97} ) )
```

But

```
Println(string([]int{97} ) )
```

would cause compile error

```
cannot convert []int literal (type []int) to type string
```

The behavior is confusing to me. If it handles `string(int)` the same as `string(int32)`, why it handles `string([]int)` different from `string([]int32)`?

Comment: "If it handles string(int) the same as string(int32)" - no, it doesn't. `go vet` prints a warning on `string(int)`

Comment: thanks for mentioning `go vet` which is new to me (new Go learner :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rune` which represents a unicode code point is an alias for `int32`. So effectively `string([]int32{})` is the same as `string([]rune{})` which converts a slice of runes (something like the charaters of a `string`) to `string`. This is useful.

`int` is not `int32` nor `rune`, so it's not logical what converting `[]int` to `string` should be, it's ambiguous, so it's not allowed by the language spec.

Converting an integer number to `string` results in a string value with a single `rune`. [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> **Conversions to and from a string type**
>
> 1. Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to `"\uFFFD"`.

This is confusing to many, as many expects the conversion result to be the (decimal) representation as string. The Go authors have recognized this, and have taken steps to depcecate and remove it from the language in the future. In Go 1.15, `go vet` already warns for such conversion. [Go 1.15 release notes: Vet:](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#vet)

> #### New warning for string(x)
>
> The vet tool now warns about conversions of the form `string(x)` where `x` has an integer type other than `rune` or `byte`. Experience with Go has shown that many conversions of this form erroneously assume that `string(x)` evaluates to the string representation of the integer x. It actually evaluates to a string containing the UTF-8 encoding of the value of `x`. For example, `string(9786)` does not evaluate to the string `"9786"`; it evaluates to the string `"\xe2\x98\xba"`, or `"☺"`.
>
> Code that is using `string(x)` correctly can be rewritten to `string(rune(x))`. Or, in some cases, calling `utf8.EncodeRune(buf, x)` with a suitable byte slice `buf` may be the right solution. Other code should most likely use `strconv.Itoa` or `fmt.Sprint`.
>
> This new vet check is enabled by default when using `go test`.
>
> **We are considering prohibiting the conversion in a future release of Go.** That is, the language would change to only permit `string(x)` for integer `x` when the type of `x` is `rune` or `byte`. Such a language change would not be backward compatible. We are using this vet check as a first trial step toward changing the language.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. just found it's a bit frustrating to have to go through the language spec. would be easier if the behavior can be more obvious. :) and thanks for metnioning go 1.15. i just installed 1.14.6 a few weeks ago.

Comment: Every language has some oddities, especially when it comes to type conversions. The nice thing about Go is that there is a clear spec that defines the language behavior. I recommend getting familiar with it.

Comment: is it possible to enable `go vet` by default for `go build` or `go run` (like `gcc -Wall`)?

Comment: @pynexj Not sure about `go build` and `go run`, but `go test` automatically runs `vet` by default.